# How to swap css class depending on the page the user is on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<nav id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active homePage">
            <a href="index.php" title="Homepage">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="resourcesPage">
            <a href="resources.php" title="Resources">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="resources_restaurants.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Restaurants</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources_businesses.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Businesses</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources_events.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources_elearning.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>e-Learning</a></li>
                <li><a href="resource_other.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="spiPage">
            <a href="#">Spi</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="spi_qa.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Q&A</a></li>
                <li><a href="spi_knowledge.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Knowledge</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="aboutPage">
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contactPage">
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

How can I modify the below script so if any of the resources page is in the Url, the `LI` with the class `resourcesPage` will have the `active` class. Only one of the parent `LI` will have the active class.

```
$(function() {
    var pathName = getPageName(window.location.pathname);

    if (pathName.split("_").toLowerCase() == 1) { //if the path is anything related to the home page
        $("."+pathName+"Page").addClass("active"); //add the 'active' class to the homePage LI and remove it from the rest
    }
    else if (pathName.split("_").toLowerCase() == 1) { //if the path is anything related to the resources page
        $("."+pathName+"Page").addClass("active"); //add the 'active' class to the resourcePage LI and remove it from the rest
    }
    else if (pathName.split("_").toLowerCase() == 1) { //if the path is anything related to the spi page
        $("."+pathName+"Page").addClass("active"); //add the 'active' class to the spiPage LI and remove it from the rest
    }
    else if (pathName.split("_").toLowerCase() == 1) { //if the path is anything related to the about page
        $("."+pathName+"Page").addClass("active"); //add the 'active' class to the aboutPage LI and remove it from the rest
    }
    else if (pathName.split("_").toLowerCase() == 1) { //if the path is anything related to the contact page
        $("."+pathName+"Page").addClass("active"); //add the 'active' class to the contactPage LI and remove it from the rest
    }
});
```

UPDATE:

```
<nav id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active homePage" id="home">
            <a href="index.php" title="Nur4Nas Homepage">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="resourcesPage" id="resources">
            <a href="resources.php" title="Resources">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="resources_ins"><a href="resources_insurance.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Institutions</a></li>
                <li id="resources_restaurants"><a href="resources_restaurant.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Restaurants</a></li>
                <li id="resources_businesses"><a href="resources_businesses.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Businesses</a></li>
                <li id="resources_events"><a href="resources_events.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Events</a></li>
                <li id="resources_elearn"><a href="resources_elearn.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>e-Learning</a></li>
                <li id="resources_other"><a href="resources_other.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="spiPage" id="spi">
            <a href="spi.php" title="Spi">Spi</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="spi_qa"><a href="spi_qa.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Q&A</a></li>
                <li id="spi_knowledge"><a href="spi_knowledge.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Knowledge</a></li>
                <li id="spi_marriage"><a href="spi_family.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Family</a></li>
                <li id="spi_dwif"><a href="spi_inter.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Inter</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="expressionPage" id="expression">
            <a href="expression.php" title="Expression">Expression</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="expression_multimedia"><a href="expression_multimedia.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Multimedia</a></li>
                <li id="expression_eduact"><a href="expression_eduact.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Education/Activity</a></li>
                <li id="expression_ouwo"><a href="expression_ouwo.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Our World</a></li>
                <li id="expression_poems"><a href="expression_poems.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Poems</a></li>
                <li id="expression_other"><a href="expression_other.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="aboutPage" id="about">
            <a href="aboutus.php" title="About Us">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contactPage" id="contact">
            <a href="contactus.php" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

So for example, in the code above, if I am on the homepage, the `home` LI ID will be set to active (as shown above). If I am on the resources or any of the sub resources page, the `resources` LI ID will be set to `active` class and all the other LI will remove the `active` class.

Comment: Your script doesn't do what the comments say it does.  In fact, it appears to do the same thing over and over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what solved the issue for me:

```
<nav id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active homePage" id="home">
                <a href="index.php" title="Nur4Nas Homepage">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="resourcesPage" id="resources">
                <a href="resources.php" title="Resources">Resources</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="resources_ins"><a href="resources_insurance.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Institutions</a></li>
                    <li id="resources_restaurants"><a href="resources_restaurant.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Restaurants</a></li>
                    <li id="resources_businesses"><a href="resources_businesses.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Businesses</a></li>
                    <li id="resources_events"><a href="resources_events.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Events</a></li>
                    <li id="resources_elearn"><a href="resources_elearn.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>e-Learning</a></li>
                    <li id="resources_other"><a href="resources_other.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Other</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="spiPage" id="spi">
                <a href="spi.php" title="Spi">Spi</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="spi_qa"><a href="spi_qa.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Q&A</a></li>
                    <li id="spi_knowledge"><a href="spi_knowledge.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Knowledge</a></li>
                    <li id="spi_marriage"><a href="spi_family.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Family</a></li>
                    <li id="spi_dwif"><a href="spi_inter.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Inter</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="expressionPage" id="expression">
                <a href="expression.php" title="Expression">Expression</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="expression_multimedia"><a href="expression_multimedia.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Multimedia</a></li>
                    <li id="expression_eduact"><a href="expression_eduact.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Education/Activity</a></li>
                    <li id="expression_ouwo"><a href="expression_ouwo.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Our World</a></li>
                    <li id="expression_poems"><a href="expression_poems.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Poems</a></li>
                    <li id="expression_other"><a href="expression_other.php"><span class="icon elem3"></span>Other</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="aboutPage" id="about">
                <a href="aboutus.php" title="About Us">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="contactPage" id="contact">
                <a href="contactus.php" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Script:

```
var pathName = getPageName(window.location.pathname);
var getSubPath = pathName.split("_")[0];

$('.ulHeaderMenu li').removeClass('active');
$('.ulHeaderMenu li.'+getSubPath+'Page').addClass('active');
```

Thanks to @lassombra for the pointer to have it working.

Answer (score 2):

A script that would do what you are looking for is essentially

```
$(function() {
  var pathName = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
  $('li[href='+pathName+']').addClass('active').parents('li').addClass('active');
});
```

This is generally considered bad design and non-performant but it will do exactly what I think you are trying to do.

The reason it will be non-performant is because you aren't using efficient selectors (you don't have id attributes directly derived from the page name for example so you can't map 1:1).  These kind of jquery selectors traverse the entire DOM looking for matches, and as such can't get exactly what you want.  In contrast, if you have an id which is just a parsed version of the page name, then you don't have to traverse the entire DOM, and you can use $('#'+idName) which will be very fast.

More information about jquery performance: http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck

---

EDIT: Added more about actually refactoring the original document:

Rewriting the original document with ids which are the pathnames without the .php gets you:

```
<nav id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active homePage" id="index">
            <a href="index.php" title="Homepage">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="resourcesPage" id="resources">
            <a href="resources.php" title="Resources">Resources</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="resources_restaurants"><a href="resources_restaurants.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Restaurants</a></li>
                <li id="resources_businesses"><a href="resources_businesses.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Businesses</a></li>
                <li id="resouces_events"><a href="resources_events.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Events</a></li>
                <li id="resouces_elearning"><a href="resources_elearning.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>e-Learning</a></li>
                <li id="resouces_other><a href="resources_other.php"><span class="icon elem0"></span>Other</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="spiPage">
            <a href="#">Spi</a>
            <ul>
                <li id="spi_qa"><a href="spi_qa.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Q&A</a></li>
                <li id="spi_knowledge"><a href="spi_knowledge.php"><span class="icon elem1"></span>Knowledge</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="aboutPage">
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="contactPage">
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

With that you could rewrite your javascript to be:

```
$(function() {
  //This double split is an easy way to parse out just the filename portion
  //it equivalently means "id" in this case
  var pathName = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1].split('.')[0];
  //find limits results to only li tags, it is a safety method which can be
  //ignored if you're confident in your html structure
  $('#'+pathName).find('li').addClass('active').parents('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: How would I use the ID? Thanks for the response btw.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to include a refactored page design which would be able to use the ID, give me about 10 minutes.

Comment: @Rune FS thanks for the edit, I can't believe I missed that, I work in javascript 40 hours a week!

Comment: your welcome, it's an honest mistake and if this is the only time you'll make it I bow to thee :)

Comment: @Rune FS Oh hell no, I make that all the time.  I just usually catch it myself!  (When uglify fails)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Should I change the outer LI to the ID? Because technically the parent LI or the inner LI is what needs the class and if something doesn't have a sub UL, that page will make it active. Thanks

Comment: When I go to the resources page (localhost/mysite/resources.php) the resources LI doesn't get highlited :/ I would like to remove active from home and add it to the resources parent LI

Comment: are you navigating to each page or using ajax?  Also, you have everything in a subfolder, so `var pathName = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1].split('.')[0];` would have to be changed to take the third part of the first split not the seond `var pathName = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2].split('.')[0];`  I recommend trying different variations of this in the browser console to get a feel for what they produce so you can better understand what's going on.  To make it come off the previous just add a line `$('li').removeClass('active');` before the last line.

Comment: I am going to put all the pages in one main folder and was planning on using the script to change the class based on finding some text in the ID.

Comment: did you try my example with the updates from my last comment?  I think you'll find that the script does what you are looking for at least for resources files for the moment.  I feel like you are needing more basic javascript/html configuration, and I can help with that, but perhaps a chat would be more appropriate?

Comment: @lassombra I never get an update when you reply :/. I will test it out tonight and update you. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my question to how I have it set up. I hope it is clearer now. Also the second script above, gets the `DisplayThis` in the Url `http://localhost/DisplayThis/index.php`

Answer (score 2):

you can also use PHP to do so in case the user has JS disabled:

```
<?php if(expression) $style = "active"; else $style="";

<div class="something <?php echo $style ?>" >
</div>
```

some people disable JS, some browsers don't have good JS functions, it is a good practice to make important stuff be server side.

Comment: This was true 10 years ago.  It was even true 2 years ago.  Today, if someone is browsing without javascript, they should EXPECT important features to not work.  Unless your application is a critical business application (such as a bank, or bill payment site) this just isn't the truth anymore.  Your solution does work, but it can quickly muddy the readability.  Still, +1 for offering a server side solution.

Comment: @lassombra i still find some android devices and some internet cafes who disable JS, it is quite annoying, in most common cases you wouldn't get a problem but i still face this dilemma every now and then. JS would be better since it is cleaner and has less resources consuming on the server (works client side), but it is always better to have your project working on many platform, (something that gets harder everyday, which is supposed to be the opposite..), and thanks, i really needed that +1 :)

Comment: I +1 for the server side. But what is the expression I am using?

Comment: it depends on what you use to decide to use, for example, you create 3 buttons, button1 would set $_SESSION['style'] to 1, button 2 sets it to 2 and so on.  then expression would be if($_SESSION['style'] == 1) $style="1.css";